# Абсолютное позиционирование для элемента, где родительский контейнер text-overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Друзья получилась такая ситуация. Есть контейнер, для которого подключен плагин слайдера.

Если что плагин [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Для этого контейнера применен text-overflow:hidden

Также заказчик хочет, что бы при наведение на элементы слайдера они увеличивались на 10% в размере. Все это реализовал, но кажется технически сделать так не получится, поскольку сама прокрутка слайдера должна быть infinity, но также надо скрыть остальные элементы, которые не видимы в данный момент, и получается при наведение, элемент не может выйти за рамки области видимости родительского контейнера.

Вопрос собственно в том можно ли решить проблему так, что бы эффект слайдера остался, и можно было увеличивать элементы на 10% в размере при наведение?

**Для того что бы понять проблему и увидеть ее своими глазами, Посмотрите раздел "акции на главной странице сайта:** [plus.iseeweb.ru](http://plus.iseeweb.ru)

Comment: дайте контейнеру padding, который будет больше чем 10%-ое увеличение.

Comment: но маргины между элементами должны быть в 20 пикселей. если я так сделаю будет видно часть скрытых элементов.

Comment: а вы дайте их не со всех сторон, а только вертикально.

Comment: ну хорошо, вертикально проблему решит, но горизонтально то всеравно картинки будут резаться, так как подойдут элементы к граням

Comment: напоминает анекдот про наркомана и ребенка в песочнице - "а у нее колесиков нет". можно решить. `transform-origin` использовать, например. проблема не стоит отдельного вопроса на стеке - это частный случай, с которым думающий человек способен разобраться сам.

Comment: Вы можете мне конкретное решение предложить? Я с такой проблемой еще не сталкивался, и думать над решением достаточно трудно. Я не из тех, кто сразу бежит сюда при первой же неудачи, но когда я захожу в тупик я спрашиваю более опытных специалистов. Если вы конкретно сможете помочь я буду вам очень благодарен и признателен. И сам научусь заодно.

Comment: transform-origin вы говорите использовать что бы повернуть анимацию внутрь видимой области? Хорошо, как вариант окей, но есть ли возможность выйти за приделы видимой области? Меня интересует или есть такая возможность вообще в природе

Comment: я бы использовал вариант с `padding` и попытался бы уменьшить ширину вьюпорта слайдера. писать код за вас не готов.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку. решил через transform-origin